# Server closes connection when trying to connect Java application to Redshift database

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to connect a Java application to a Redshift database.  When I run DriverManager.getConnection(), it sits for a long time (minutes) and finally throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: 
   [Amazon](600001) The server closed the connection.
at com.amazon.support.channels.TLSSocketChannel.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.support.channels.TLSSocketChannel.doHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.support.channels.TLSSocketChannel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.checkSSL(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

I can connect using the same connection string and credentials from SQL Workbench on the same machine.  Also, if I supply bad credentials to the connection, it gives an authentication error.  So I don't believe this is an Amazon security issue, which seems to be the most common reason for an inability to connect.

Other ideas?

Update: The mystery deepens.  Other members of the team are able to check out the code and run it successfully.  We have the driver in our team's shared maven repository.

Comment: Hanging for a long time is an indication that the network connection was unsuccessful. What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with your Redshift instance? Are you trying to connect from a computer on the Internet? If so, is your Redshift instance publicly accessible (in a public subnet, domain name resolves to a Public IP)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Right now, it's open to the world.  And wouldn't any of those issues also stop connections from my SQL query tool (running on same machine) from working?  And prevent authentication checks?

Comment: Ah! Okay, so on some machines it works and on some it hangs. Quite clearly, it would be due to something on the machines rather than the Redshift configuration. What client/driver are you using to connect? Are you using the [Redshift JDBC Driver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes - the 4.2 compatible driver. 1.2.12.1017.  And we're all using the same one from a shared maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

Well... not sure what the problem was.  But I did an Eclipse update and it went away.